# trying to build Boost MPI, but the lib files are not created. What's going on?

Tags: boost, build, configure, boost-mpi

I am trying to run a program with Boost MPI, but the thing is I don't have the .lib. So I try to create one by following the instruction at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html#mpi.config

The instruction says "For many users using LAM/MPI, MPICH, or OpenMPI, configuration is almost automatic", I got myself OpenMPI in C:\, but I didn't do anything more with it. Do we need to do anything with it? I also got myself MPICH2 in Program Files, and didn't do anything more with it as well. At this point of the instruction is where I am quite unsure about what exactly do we have to do.

Beside that, another statement from the instruction: "If you don't already have a file user-config.jam in your home directory, copy tools/build/v2/user-config.jam there." Well, I simply do what it says. I got myself "user-config.jam" in C:\boost_1_43_0> along with "using mpi ;" into the file.

Next, this is what I've done: bjam --with-mpi

```
C:\boost_1_43_0>bjam --with-mpi
WARNING: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
         failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
         for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
         suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
warning: Unable to construct ./stage-unversioned
warning: Unable to construct ./stage-unversioned

Component configuration:

    - date_time                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...found 1 target...


The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    C:\boost_1_43_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    C:\boost_1_43_0\stage\lib


C:\boost_1_43_0>
```

I see that there are many libs in C:\boost_1_43_0\stage\lib, but I see no trace of libboost_mpi-vc100-mt-1_43.lib or libboost_mpi-vc100-mt-gd-1_43.lib at all. These are the libraries required for linking in mpi applications.

What could possibly gone wrong when libraries are not being built?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect it's just not reading your user-config.jam... When the build refers to, and searches for, the user-config.jam it does so in the %HOME% location. Not in the root directory of the Boost sources, nor in the current dir. But you can make it use a specific user-config.jam file with an option: `bjam --user-config=user-config.jam ...`. Which will look for it only in the current dir. Or you could also specify a full path to the file. You should read the comments in the mpi.jam tool file ([mpi.jam](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release/Boost_1_43_0/tools/build/v2/tools/mpi.jam)) as it explains under which conditions it will automatically set up the mpi tools. Specifically the note about having `mpic++` in your path.

Answer (score 0):

I built boost 1.55 with mpi with the following commands:
./bjam link=shared --prefix=/software/boost_1.55 install

vim tools/build/v2/user-config.jam

-->> at the end of user-config.jam  "using mpi ;"  (without quotes)

./b2  link=shared --prefix=/software/boost_1.55 install

If I provide --with-mpi I got the same problem, therefore I've built it that way.